# values are not receiving dynamically in REST API

Tags: apex, rest, developer-console, developer

I wrote the batch and pass the values to REST apex class but when executing the endpoint url it doesn't take the values of fields it only takes names.

### this is my batch job

```
global class WebinarListUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.Stateful,Database.AllowsCallouts{

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {   
        return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id,Name,LightiningEd__Start_Time__c,LightiningEd__Finish_Time__c,LightiningEd__Registration_URL__c,LightiningEd__Expired__c,LightiningEd__SCO_ID__c FROM LightiningEd__Webinar__c WHERE LightiningEd__Retrival_Date__c= YESTERDAY');
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Webinar__c> scope){
        List<Webinar__c> wlist = new  List<Webinar__c>();
        for(Webinar__c w : scope){

            String eventid = w.LightiningEd__SCO_ID__c;
            System.debug('eventId::'+eventid);

SelectedWebinarListUpdate.updateWebinar('xxxxxxxx.com','test12345','https://meet95927113.adobeconnect.com',eventid);
        }

    }
     global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
       System.debug('Closing the batch job');

   }
}
```

here i'm reading the event id from SOQL query and pass that value to REST API but when executing at endpoint it doesn't receiving the value.

### this is my rest api :

```
global class SelectedWebinarListUpdate {

    @future(callout=true)
    global static void updateWebinar(String username,String password,String url,String eventid){
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req =  new HttpRequest();  
        HttpResponse res =  new HttpResponse();  
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
        EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);              
        req.setEndpoint(url+'/api/xml?action=report-event-participants-complete-information&account-id=1300650024&session=apac1breezdaeh3dn9nnrbtdz3&sco-id=eventid');                      
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Accept','application/json'); 
        try {
            res = http.send(req); 
            System.debug('MyResult == :'+res.getBody());            
            XMLparserUpdate s = new XMLparserUpdate(res.getBody());
            System.debug('Response value'+s);   

        }catch(System.CalloutException e){
               System.debug('Callout error: '+ e); 

      } //return res;

    }

}
```

here in this line

```
 req.setEndpoint(url+'/api/xml?action=report-event-participants-complete-information&account-id=1300650024&session=apac1breezdaeh3dn9nnrbtdz3&sco-id=eventid');
```

it doesn't receiving the eventid it just prints eventid.

Answer (score 1):

As the color coding of your `SelectedWebinarListUpdate` class hints, the `eventid` parameter (black text) is not being used in the method and instead a fixed text string 'eventid' (red/brown text) is being used. The quick fix is just to append the variable to the string:

```
req.setEndpoint(url+'/api/xml?action=report-event-participants-complete-information&account-id=1300650024&session=apac1breezdaeh3dn9nnrbtdz3&sco-id=' + eventid);
```

Note that a cleaner way to build URLs that also ensures that values are correctly escaped is to use the [PageReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm) class:

```
PageReference pr = new PageReference(url + '/api/xml');
Map<String, String> params = pr.getParameters();
params.put('action', 'report-event-participants-complete-information');
params.put('account-id', '1300650024');  
params.put('session', 'apac1breezdaeh3dn9nnrbtdz3'); 
params.put('sco-id', eventid);
req.setEndpoint(pr.getUrl());
```